# Get POST API Responses shown in Shopify product page/s

Tags: api, shopify

Need assistance, I have gotten it right to have the POST API show the responses as it should.
I need assistance with getting these responses shown on the product pages on Shopify, as they are product qty's from the supplier. I am new at this so please be easy on me...

Running the API in VisualCode with Thunder Client.
Have the following JS running but dont know if i am on the right path, it is then linked to an html to actually show the results.

```
fetch("URL")
 .then((response) => {
 if (response.ok) {
  return response.json();
} else {
  throw new Error("NETWORK RESPONSE ERROR");
    }
  })
  .then(data => {
console.log(data);
 display(data)
  })
 .catch((error) => {
 return console.error("FETCH ERROR:", error);
});

const token = localStorage.getItem('token')

const response = await fetch(apiURL, {
method: 'POST',
headers: {
  'Content-type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': `Bearer ${ttoken}`,
  }
 })
```

Comment: Sorry your question is a bit vague. Can you show us the code you're having problem with, and your attempt at solving it?

Comment: fetch("URL")
  .then((response) => {
    if (response.ok) {
      return response.json();
    } else {
      throw new Error("NETWORK RESPONSE ERROR");
    }
  })
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    display(data)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    return console.error("FETCH ERROR:", error);
  });

const token = localStorage.getItem('token')

const response = await fetch(apiURL, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${ttoken}`,
  }
})

Comment: Ok so, that is your POST call. You want to display the result in the page. To be able to give you an insightful answer we need how the response look alike, how is your html and how do you want to display the data.